# Rate of evaporation of water

Tags: water, evaporation

In our everyday life, does the temperature or humidity have a greater effect on how fast things dry? Are there any theories/models that explain this quantitatively?

Comment: *"Are there any theories/models that explain this quantitatively?"* Of course there are. They live mostly in thermodynamics and statistical mechanics, but they are complicated by the fact that many of the ill-specified "things" you probably care about have a lot of structure. Phase change physics is fun. Or at least if can be if you come properly equipped.

Comment: Fysics is phun; always! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It is just a mass transfer that is driven by the difference in vapor pressure of the liquid versus vapor pressure in the vapor phase.

If the relative humidity is 100% then you are not going to get any evaporation.  Even at 100 °F.

But if the humidity is 0 you will get pretty good evaporation at 40 °F.

All that really matters is relative humidity.  But as you increase temperature for the same absolute humidity the relative humidity goes down.